# Solving recurrence relation T(n) = 3T(2n/3) + cn

Tags: recurrence

I'm trying to solve this relation by iteration method.

I'm understanding that first part of solution is `3^rT(2/3)^r * n`.  But isn't the rest of it `cn + 3n + 5n + 7n ....` ?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a math question, not programming.

Comment: It's an algorithms question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we repeatedly re-substitute for `T`:

[image]

After `m` iterations. When do we stop? Assuming that the stopping condition is `n = 1`:

[image]

Therefore the final result is:

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

Some numerical tests to confirm this result:

```
N       T(N)
---------------------
1000    262143000
2000    1048574000
3000    3145725000
4000    8388604000
5000    20971515000
6000    25165818000
7000    29360121000
8000    67108856000
9000    75497463000
10000   83886070000
```

Log-log plot:

[image]

The gradient `m` of this plot is such that `T(N) = ϴ(N^m)`. The result `m = 2.70562` is rather close to the theoretical value of `2.70951`.